# Why does a hyperlink and a button styled with the same CSS look different?

Tags: html, css

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnaDG/)

My HTML:

```
<a href="register" class="btn btn-splash-action">Register</a><br>
<input name="SignIn" type="submit" class="btn btn-splash-action" value="Sign In" alt="Sign In" />
```

My CSS:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-splash-action {
    background: #09F;
    border: 1px solid #0b0e07;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Basically I've got a hyperlink with the CSS classes applied to it as a button element. However they visually have different widths and Firebug calculates the widths as different as well.

I've got the same problem in IE10 and FireFox 26.

If I'm applying the same styling to both elements, why do they look different?

**EDIT:**
Updated the JSFiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/DnaDG/1/

Trying to reset the padding, margin, and border using the `.btn` class but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases the browser starts with default styles for the corresponding elements and then adds your styles to those. The `<a>` tag and the `<input>` tag have different default (starting) styles.

Here are the default styles Safari uses for `<a>` elements:

```
color: -webkit-link;
text-decoration: underline;
cursor: auto;
```

And here are some of the default styles for `<input>` elements:

```
-webkit-align-items: flex-start;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
color: buttontext;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-left: 6px;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-top-style: outset;
border-right-style: outset;
border-bottom-style: outset;
border-left-style: outset;
border-top-color: buttonface;
border-right-color: buttonface;
border-bottom-color: buttonface;
border-left-color: buttonface;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
background-color: buttonface;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

There are actually a whole lot more in addition to those. Also, different browsers have different defaults.

Comment: so how do I completely reset the button and anchor styles before applying my own across all browsers?

Comment: add your own style rules to replace the browser defaults

Comment: can you please look at my updated JSFiddle. I tried to reset the styles using the .btn class but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: As a suggestion, you might benefit from becoming familiar with the developer tools of your favorite web browser. (All modern browsers have pretty good one these days.) You can simply inspect the element(s) in question and enable/disable rules with simple mouse clicks. That's a much much faster (and simpler) way to fix your problem than a comment discussion.

Comment: Trying to use Firebug to see whats going on but I can't fathom it out. Plus if I fix it on Firefox then it still may look different in IE. I've just decided to ditch trying to style a hyperlink like a button and replaced it with an actual button element. Done.

Answer (score 1):

The default styling for each element is different... A hyperlink doesn't have a border for example, and there are some styles that you are not overriding, so the element retains those. Thus, not all the styles from your css will have an effect. Does that make sense? Hope this helps!